# Can't SSH PC running 2 network cards from second network

Tags: networking, ssh, nic

I've got an Ubuntu PC (Machine A) with 2 network cards connected to 2 different networks.

Machine A can be ssh'd from a different machine that is on its first network (eno1), but can't be ssh'd from a machine (Machine B) on its second network (enp5s0). This isn't just limited to SSH, I also can't access the MQTT server running on Machine A.

I can SSH from Machine A -> Machine B, but not from Machine B -> Machine A. I assume this is some firewall/routing issue, but that's all I've got.

Machine A:
  LAN1 IP: 10.100.43.44
  LAN2 IP: 165.10.10.10

Machine B:
  IP: 165.10.10.11

**Machine A**
ip addr show

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:7f:54:9e:e2:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0
    inet 10.100.43.44/24 brd 10.100.43.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ca7f:54ff:fe9e:e250/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:7f:54:3f:af:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 165.10.10.10/22 metric 100 brd 162.10.11.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ca7f:54ff:fe3f:afd1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ip Route

```
default via 10.100.43.1 dev eno1 proto static
default via 165.10.8.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 165.10.10.10 metric 100
10.100.43.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.43.44
165.10.8.0/22 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 165.10.10.10 metric 100
165.10.8.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 165.10.10.10 metric 100
```

**Machine B:**
ip addr show

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:10:c9:b9:4a:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 165.10.10.11/22 brd 162.10.11.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e10:c9ff:feb9:4afc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route show

```
default via 165.10.8.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 20100
165.10.8.0/22 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 165.10.10.11 metric 100
```

I can also ping both ways between each machine

Comment: Please provide output of commands `ip addr show` and `ip route show` from both machines.

Comment: try ping b to a

Comment: @raj Posted below

Comment: You should have edited your question and add the information there, and not post it as answer. Edited it for you. Please delete the "answer".

Comment: Your routing table seem to be OK, except maybe for two default gateways on machine A - having two default gateways is usually asking for problems. However, if ping works, then most probably it's not a routing issue. It may be a firewall issue. Try disabling firewall completely on both machines and check. Or it may be ssh server on machine A listening only on one interface.

Answer (score -1):

I assume it is the 165.10.10.x addresses that are having the issue?

These are not part of any private subnet allocation, therefore your router, and systems will be treating them as public IP's and sending them to your gateway.

Unless you own these addresses (current allocation have these addresses assigned to Pretoria, South Africa ), I would suggest first you change to a /24 in one of the private classes:

```
Class A: 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
Class B: 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
Class C: 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```